# Multiple Position Selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have multiple Div's that I am using as buttons. If I set the postition to relative I can use float left to put them all on one row next to eachother. They also appear at the top of the parent div. I want the buttons to appear at the bottom of the parent div. Is it possible to give an element two position values as in

```
position: relative;
float: left;
```

and also

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

I have a feeling this is a logic error of some kind and I am not sure how to do this logic.

Comment: No you can not use two positions at one time in one css it will overwrite each other

Answer (score 0):

just put them into wrapper

```
<style>div.buttons{position:absolute;bottom:0;}</style>
<div class="buttons">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if float is problem, use display:inline-block; for positioning add `position:relative` to the parent div, and use `position:absolute` to child divs.

Please note with display inline-block you need to extra hack for IE7 `*display:inline` (if you are still supporting it), and if you see white space btw buttons, [refer](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)